# django compressor is it possible to compress all files to one file?

Tags: django, django-templates

Is it possible with `django compressor`?
Or, can I name a `{% compress %}` tag and later add some additional files there? (to be compressed together)

For example, assume in `layout.html` I have:

```
{% compress js file main_js_files %}
<script src="..../a.js"></script>
{% endcompress %}
```

and then in `template.html`: (which extends `layout.html`)

```
{% compress js file main_js_files %}
<script src="..../b.js"></script>
{% endcompress %}
```

and finally there will be one single file, contains both `a.js` and `b.js`.